# Making RhinoMock Stub Return Value Dependent on a Paramter

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to set a "default" return value for a RhinoMock stub?

For ex: I have a method that takes in an `int` from 1-175 and returns a bool:

```
internal bool myFunction(int number)
```

I want to stub this in Rhino Mock so that it only returns `true` if the `number` is 2 or 3, and false otherwise:

```
myClass.Stub(x => x.MyFunction(2)).Return(true);
myClass.Stub(x => x.MyFunction(3)).Return(true);
// return false otherwise
```

However, if I pass any other int in my test (eg. 100), the function will also return true. I want it to return false all cases except the two I listed above. How can I do this?

Comment: one way `if(number == 2 || number == 3) { myClass.Stub(...);}` etc... might be a better way (hence this comment vs answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Do` to provide a method implementation with access to the input parameters

```
myClass.Stub(_ => _.MyFunction(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
    .Do((Func<int, bool>)(number => {
        return number == 2 || number == 3;
    }));
```